# overflow in copied version of linked list

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, access-violation

I have a linked list class.
It includes a copy constructor:

```
LinkedListStorage(const LinkedListStorage &other) :root(NULL)
{
    size = other.size;
    count = other.count;
    node *cur = other.root;
    node *end = NULL;

    while(cur->next != NULL)
    {
        node* x = new node;
        x->word = cur->word;

        if(!root)
        {
            root = x;
            end = root;
        }
        else
        {
            end->next = x;
            end = x;
        }

        cur = cur->next;
    }
}
```

In the class i run it through a method to write the linked list to file, however while said method works for the original list, the copied version of the list causes an access violation, stepping through the list the final entry to the list as it is copied points to 0x00000000 as expected, however by the time it gets to the write function the pointer for the last node ends up pointing to 0xcdcdcdcd, no code runs between the attempted copy, and the use of the write function so it must be the copy constructor, however i can not for the life of me figure out where it is going wrong.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: 0xcdcdcdcd usually means uninitialized valiable

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the rest of the class but maybe you need to initialise `x->next`, i.e. `node* x = new node; x->word = cur->word; x->next = NULL;`

Comment: @John You were correct, setting x->next = cur->next fixed the problem, it wasn't intitialising the ->next of the final element because of this. Thanks a lot!

That said, this isn't an answer, so what should i do about choosing the correct answer?

Comment: @SteHawkins I'll convert it to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without seeing the rest of the class but maybe you need to initialise `x->next`, i.e.

```
node* x = new node;
x->word = cur->word;
x->next = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you don't copy the last element. Change:

```
while(cur->next != NULL)
```

to

```
while(cur != NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are storing a pointer to the last entry in your list in `end` but when iterating over the list you check for `->next != NULL` which you don't seem to be setting on `end`. I'm not sure that's what's causing your current problem but it seems wrong. :)

**Edit**:
Since you also store the length of the list in `count` you have triple redundant information:

1. `end`
2. `->next == NULL`
3. `count`
   You have to be careful to keep those in sync if you really need all of them.

Also: You should use nullptr instead of NULL if you can.